# How to get response variable name from summary.glm

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rbinom(10, 1, prob=.5)
x <- runif(10)
m <- glm(y~x, family=binomial)
s <- summary(m)
```

I am looking for some function, `foo(s)`, that I can use to return `"y"`.

Comment: You could (manually) parse `s$call` (which outputs `glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial)` or the model formula `m$formula` (outputs `y ~ x`).

Comment: @nrussell, thanks. That's a nice start. Is there a clean string function to extract the value prior to the "~"?

Comment: Actually you might not even need to parse / use regex on this - `as.character(m$formula)` returns `[1] "~" "y" "x"`, a length three vector - so in this case `as.character(m$formula)[2]` should do the job. You might have to test this on a few different formulas to see how robust this approach is, but I would guess that `~` is always the first element, the response variable is always the second, and the independent variable(s) are the rest of the vector.

Comment: @nrussell, in this case I need to work on the summary `s`. I'm looking at `?sub` right now.

Comment: `strsplit(as.character(s$call)[2],"\\s~\\s")[[1]][1]` likes like a viable option.

Comment: @nrussell, you can add it as an answer if you'd like, & I'll upvote it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a better answer, but

```
as.character(attributes(s$terms)$variables[[2]])
```

works

Answer (score 4):

Another option -

```
R> strsplit(as.character(s$call)[2],"\\s~\\s")[[1]][1]
[1] "y"
```

Comment: @akrun That would definitely work in this case, but I was trying to generalize for cases where the formula could be something like `y_var ~ x` (and the associated call would be `glm(formula = y_var ~ x)`) which would only return `y`, no?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `terms()` function, you can do

```
with(attributes(terms(m)), as.character(variables[response+1]))
# [1] "y"
```

This should be robust for many different formulas. This is a similar method to the one used by the `delete.response()` function.

Comment: Yes. Just change `m` to `s`.

Comment: I just had a chance to check it ;-). Thanks for the suggestion.